# Php, DbSimple error

Tags: php

I work with DbSimple in my site-engine. Everything worked fine but some time ago I began to get an error:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in Z:\home\localhost\www\ololo\DbSimple\Generic.php on line 113

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in Z:\home\localhost\www\ololo\DbSimple\Generic.php on line 133

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in Z:\home\localhost\www\ololo\DbSimple\Mysql.php on line 73

Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'mysqlErrorHandler' not found or invalid function name in Z:\home\localhost\www\ololo\DbSimple\Generic.php on line 1278
SELECT * FROM `configuration`
NULL
```

What can it be?

Comment: It appears the API has changed. Did you upgrade your PHP or DbSimple?

Comment: Yeah, as I understand, PHP was upgraded. But DbSimple is an old one library :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you upgraded PHP from 5.2.x to 5.3. I've seen similar issues with Joomla.

**EDIT:**

[**Deprecated features in PHP 5.3.x**](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php)

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I can't get any result from database so what functions are deprecated?

Comment: Thanks, I'll rewrite DbSimple due to that features.